# Which environment variable to set for english output, but ISO units

Tags: linux, env

which linux environment variable do I have to set for english output, but ISO/metric units for time, date, etc. ?

Currently I have in my env:

```
LC_MESSAGES=en_US
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `LC_TIME`, for other `LC_*` variables look at The Open Group's [Locale man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html).

Comment: Yes, but to what?I looked at the link, but I could not find out what I have to set where, I'm missing examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the UK locale.

```
sudo locale-gen en_UK.UTF-8
```

The system wide locales are stated in `/etc/default/locale` in Ubuntu, so give that file the contents:

```
LANG=en_UK.UTF-8
```

The instructions for this are going to vary widely from distro to distro though.